# Share npm package azure DevOps

Tags: npm, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

As for the title, I need to share `@ionic/cli` that I run in one stage to be shared with 2 other stages.

I have a stage like this:

#### Stage 1

Install project dependencies (npm install) and `@ionic/cli`

#### Stage 2 & 3

Capacitor android and iOS build as well as their sign.

The problem is that in stages 2 and 3 the pipeline can't find `ionic`.

Any solution to share the packaged previously installed globally to be accessible from them?

The only solution I found is to run the `npm install @ionic/cli` for both stages, but from my point of view isn't the right way.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Actually not yet, I saved it in cache e reinstalled it from the cache, but I have to reinstall it for both stages...